# Why cant I use char **myargs instead of char *myargs[3] while calling execvp()?

Tags: c, gcc, child-process, execvp

I have a C program to create a child process to run command "wc exec.c".

Below is the program.

```
/* Filename: exec.c*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello world (pid = %d).\n",(int) getpid());
    int ret = fork();
    if (ret < 0)
    {
            fprintf(stderr,"fork failed.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    else if (ret == 0)
    {
            printf("I am the child process (pid = %d).\n",(int) getpid());

            // Launch command wc exec.c

            char *myargs[3];
            // char **myargs ;
            myargs[0] = "wc";
            myargs[1] = "exec.c";
            myargs[2] = NULL ;
            execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
            printf("Unreachable code\n");
    }

    else
    {
            int w = wait(NULL);
            printf("I am the parent of %d (pid = %d), w = %d\n", ret, (int) getpid(), w);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program gives expected output, as child runs "wc exec.c".

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Hello world (pid = 21362).
I am the child process (pid = 21363).
 45 115 789 exec.c
I am the parent of 21363 (pid = 21362), w = 21363
-bash-4.1$
```

Just to play around I thought of declaring char *myargs[3] with a char **myargs .
Now when I try to compile gcc gives a warning.

```
-bash-4.1$ gcc -Wall exec.c
exec.c: In function âmainâ:
exec.c:32: warning: âmyargsâ may be used uninitialized in this function
-bash-4.1$
```

line 32 is this line

```
  myargs[0] = "wc";
```

Although I could not understand the meaning of this warning, the word "MAY" gcc used gave me an impression that " ok gcc gcc thinks it MAY be used uninitialized, but i have initialized myargs[0] = "wc", so although there MAY be a problem, but there is no problem."

But when I run the executable, I see that execvp() fails (as "wc exec.c") is not executed.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Hello world (pid = 21482).
I am the child process (pid = 21483).
I am the parent of 21483 (pid = 21482), w = 21483
-bash-4.1$
```

I read the man pages for execvp, and it says, the array of pointer ( passed as second argument for execvp()) should be terminated by a NULL pointer. I thought that as the third element of char **myargs is NULL, this satisfies that condition.

Whats the reason for char **myargs to not work instead of char *myargs[ ] in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make the outer pointer actually point to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to allocate space for it.

With

```
char *myargs[3];
```

you automatically allocate space for 3 `char` pointers, so you don't have a problem, but when you do

```
char **myargs;
```

your have a pointer to a `char` pointer, so if you don't point with it anywhere and you try to access it, you will cause undefined behavior.

To use the pointer to `char` pointer, you can make it point to valid memory via `malloc()` like this

```
myargs = malloc(3 * sizeof(*myargs));
if (myargs == NULL)
    doNotContinue_AllocationFailure();
myargs[0] = "some constant string";
```

and now the code is valid.

You should remember however, that the `malloc()`ed pointer must be `free()`ed when you no longer need it, for that you need to do this

```
free(myargs);
```

Comment: I see. My assumption was that when I do myargs[0] = "wc", then the memory is automatically allocated, the string "wc\0" is stored there, and its base address is returned back to myargs[0]. (like char name[] = "name").  Question on free(myargs) : Where will I use this ? Because once execvp() is executed, the process image is different right ? Anything code after execvp() wont be executed ? And if I put free(myargs) inside the code of parent , then parent does not even know that there is something like myargs ?

Comment: btw forgot to confirm that after using malloc the issue is resolved !!

Comment: @1Byn I think that should be a new question.

Comment: Will post that question sometime soon.. will try to figure out something myself... if i m not able to figure out, will ask may be tomorrow ..